# Django models: have foreign keys many to one (specific field) relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have following in my django models file :

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/cats', null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to have foreign key to its name field and its image field separately like this:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category.name, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    category_image = models.ForeignKey(Category.image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Maybe you should review your design to know what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you have a `ForeignKey` from `Product` model to `Category` model, you can access the image field in `Category` model from `Product` model by something like this : `product_obj.category.image`.

Comment: Not what was asked though as seen in the code `category_image = models.ForeignKey(Category.image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I know what he asked. I was just giving solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Cannot be done.

Django [Foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) maps to Python classes and not Python class fields.

Comment: how can I point to Python class fields then ?
This is to show each Product's category name and category image on product page

Comment: This is why I suggested a redesign. A category should probably have a name, but not an image. Products should bear their own images.